# React useEffect hook is causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

I have an useState hook on my component, it looks like this:

```
const [scoutMode, setScoutMode] = useState("camp");
const [bottomLinks, setBottomLinks] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
if (scoutMode == "weeklyProgramme") {
  setBottomLinks([
    {
      name: "Tasks",
      link: "/tasks"
  },
  {
    name: "Checklists",
    link: "/checklists"
  }
  
  ])
} else if (scoutMode == "camp") {
  setBottomLinks([
    {
      name: "Tasks",
      link: "/tasks"
  },
  {
    name: "Map",
    link: "/map"
  }
  ])
} else {
  setBottomLinks([]);
}
console.log(bottomLinks);
})
```

But bottomLinks is printend on console continuously, I have an infinite loop. I remember there was a rule that useState must never be called inside useEffect, am I wrong, or could someone explain what is happening in my code?

Comment: You can pass a dependency array as the last argument to useEffect so that it will fire only when one of the dependencies change. In your case you can use `useEffect(() => {/* .. code ...*/}, [scoutMode])` assuming you need to invoke the function when the value of scoutMode changes.

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEM:**

When you modify a component's state within useEffect hook, the component will rerender causing the useEffect to be called again; thus entering into an infinite loop. That's why you should add a dependency array as a second argument to useEffect to invoke the function when dependencies change.

**SOLUTION:**

Add a dependency array like so:

```
const [scoutMode, setScoutMode] = useState("camp");
const [bottomLinks, setBottomLinks] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
if (scoutMode == "weeklyProgramme") {
  setBottomLinks([
    {
      name: "Tasks",
      link: "/tasks"
  },
  {
    name: "Checklists",
    link: "/checklists"
  }
  
  ])
} else if (scoutMode == "camp") {
  setBottomLinks([
    {
      name: "Tasks",
      link: "/tasks"
  },
  {
    name: "Map",
    link: "/map"
  }
  ])
} else {
  setBottomLinks([]);
}
console.log(bottomLinks);
}, [scoutMode])
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but maybe add an explanation on what life cycle hook did he used to trigger this infinite loop

Comment: @Roy.B Added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must use dependencies to useEffect function know whether rerender or not, typically syntax as

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code
}, [denpendencies])
```

In your case, if you just only it's run once, you must put dependencies by []. Otherwise, if you want useEffect run each **scoutMode** change, you put dependencies by [scoutMode]

Answer (score 0):

1. It first works when rendering occurs.
   useEffect(() => {
   ...
   }, [])
2. It works whenever the state of scoutMode changes
   useEffect(() => {
   ...
   }, [scoutMode])

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` lets you perform side effects in function components. As your useEffect has state dependency(`scoutMode`) and based on this, your changing the state(`bottomLinks`) inside `useEffect`, which will cause re-render and `useEffect` will be called again, this goes on. That's why your seeing infinite loop. You need tell when to run the `useEffect` hook by adding dependancies.

In your case, you can tell useEffect to run whenever `scoutMode` changes by adding hook dependancy.

```
useEffect(() => {
 // your stuff
}, [scoutMode])
```